# npm install is not working on Window

Tags: node.js, npm-install

i'm trying install laravel mix on window and use command line to install. But when use " npm install " which shows error bellow [image: error]

and here is my package.json
[image]
anyone help me solve this! thanks so bad

Comment: Looks like you need to fix your `package.json`

Comment: It seems to be a syntax error in your `package.json`, can you show the content?

Comment: i'm edited :) pls help me

Comment: Please copy text instead of images

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with `package-lock.json`. Try deleting the file, followed by `npm install`.

Comment: u mean delete package-lock.json and reinstall ??

Comment: Correct. package-lock.json is an inventory listing. On delete and re-install, it will get created again. I believe your error is due to merge conflicts in `package-lock.json` file.